# Bulk dataframe data to redshift database table how to insert very quickly

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, dataframe, amazon-redshift

I tried many methods to insert data from dataframe to database.

No method helped me insert quickly it took 2 days and 3 days after that getting timeout error.

Here is few methods i tried

First method i converted dataframe to dictionary and tried uploading database
Here is the sample example of data looks like: Note: i'm sharing 20 rows of data but actually i have huge amount of data

```
 conn = psycopg2.connect(
     host= 'redshift-####-dev.)00000.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com'   ,   
    database= '*****',
    user='****',
    password='*****',
    port= '5439'
    )
    print("Succesful Connection to RedShift Dev")
cur = conn.cursor ()
df_dic =[{'case_id': 69370, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'working', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-
12-15'}, {'case_id': 69370, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'scenes', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'
case_id': 69370, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'intended', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id':
 69371, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'redirected', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371,
 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'ge', 'split_text_cnt': 2, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name':
 'subject', 'split_text': 'sensor', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name': 'subject',
 'split_text': 'flush', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text
': 'motion', 'split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'led', '
split_text_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'fixture', 'split_text
_cnt': 1, 'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}, {'case_id': 69371, 'column_name': 'subject', 'split_text': 'contact', 'split_text_cnt': 1,
'load_ts': '2023-12-15'}]

sql = "INSERT INTO odey.sfc_ca_sit_di (case_id,column_name,split_text,split_text_cnt,load_ts) VALUES (%(case_id)s,%(column_name)s,%(case_subject)s,%(Case_Subject_Split_Count)s,%(load_date)s)"
cur.executemany(sql, df_dic)
conn.commit()
```

@ this methods i tried

Second method i tried dataframe to database which is converting into tuple and executed query
final_out is dataframe

```
    sql = "INSERT INTO sey.sfdse_sp_di (case_id,column_name,split_text,split_text_cnt,load_ts) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"

for row in final_out.values.tolist():
    cur.execute(sql, tuple(row))
    #print(tuple(row))
    conn.commit()
```

Both methods are taking days of time

Can anyone please suggest better methods to insert data very quickly

it's huge data roughly 600 000 records data

Comment: [This famous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite) is about C language and SQLite; however it is very interesting and you may find something useful for your environment too

Comment: Write your data frame to parquet and put it in s3 then load into redshift the way your supposed to load into redshift, with copy or spectrum. Never load into redshift with inserts and updates, it’s like trying to drive a stick shift with a hook for a hand

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25454477/1319284).

The redshift documentation [calls out](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-multi-row-inserts.html) single inserts as a bad way to insert the data.

> If a COPY command is not an option and you require SQL inserts, use a multi-row insert whenever possible. Data compression is inefficient when you add data only one row or a few rows at a time.

So you should batch data into multi-row inserts. Note the maximum size supported for [a SQL command is 16MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_INSERT_30.html). So you might need more than one batch.

The preferred way though seems to be loading data through the [COPY command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading_tables_with_the_COPY_command.html).

Comment: Thanks for responding but here i'm not using any AWS service, can we insert quickly data in any other method @kutschkem

Comment: What is this then? 'redshift-####-dev.)00000.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com' That is a redshift database host, isn't it? In any case, you can try batching regardless of what your DB is, it is much nicer for things like index updates etc.

Comment: i'm just hiding the host address 'redshift-####-dev.)00000.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com'

Comment: I see. Well without knowing what DBMS this is, it's hard to answer, but try batching the inserts like I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

First off are either of these code patterns working for small amounts of data?

It is not completely clear if you have speed issue or a functionality issue based on your description. I'm going to assume each and provide some direction.

NEVER COMPLETES FOR EVEN MODERATE SIZED DATA LOADS:

I suspect that your code is not communicating with the database correctly.  There are a few possibilities and most relate to creating very large SQL statements.  Your process is inserting data to Redshift through the SQL which is slow and creates large SQL statements (not recommended for data of more than a few rows).

1. You may have a network MTU too large.  Redshift supports network MTU
   up to 1500 and larger sizes can create "hangs" and errors. See
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-drop-issues.html
2. Redshift has a SQL command size limit and issuing commands larger
   than this can create errors.
3. Any number off network issues that could be "hanging" the connection
   to Redshift.

The easiest way to see if these are happening is to observe Redshift activity on the console when you run your code and see if your query is running.  If the query isn't running and your code is waiting there is a communications issue with the database.

I suspect your query isn't running since 600K records is just not that big for Redshift.  If a network issue is causing your issue there may be network solutions but you will be better served by abandoning this method inserting and using the method described below. Do fix your connection MTU if this is incorrect as a bad MTU can cause all kinds of strange errors.

CODE COMPLETES FOR MODERATE SIZED DATA LOADS:

INSERTing VALUES in SQL is likely the slowest way to get data into Redshift. There are a number of reasons for this including data values being compiled with the query and single data connection routing through the leader node.

You need to write the data to S3 as multiple large files (1GB+). Redshift will ingest data fastest if each slice of the cluster can ingest files in parallel with all other slices. Also S3 is inefficient handling small files so having files of at least 100MB but preferably greater than 1GB will great improve S3's efficiency.

Now you will also need to get your data to S3 efficiently and doing this well means knowing something about your DBeaver equipment. As you will need to move data to S3, the same goals apply - move multiple files in parallel with a size (approximately 1GB) that S3 will handle efficiently. Your local system can likely produce local files quickly as compared to the network transfer speed so it is this speed that needs to be addressed. Once the files are produced locally transfer them to S3 with parallel network connections. 4-6 parallel connections will likely be optimal but this dependent on many factors about you DBeaver system.